# Unexpected Regex Results

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I've seen several examples on how to retrieve and remove strings between delimiters. However, I created a very simple test case and I'm getting the wrong output based on various examples. Why am I getting back the string I'd like to use as the search source instead of the string I'm searching?

```
String temp = "56.0 F (13.3C)";
String exp = "((^))";
String p = temp.replace(exp, "");
System.out.println("p=" + p);
```

I get the string `56.0F (13.3C)` as my output.

I am expecting to get `56.0F` back.

I also tried to use the pattern matcher:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(exp);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(temp);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.groupCount());
    for (int i=0; i<=matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        String groupStr = matcher.group(i);
        System.out.println(groupStr);
    }
}
```

2 is what's printed to the console

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? I've been looking at this now for a couple of hours. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is returning the string because it could not do any replacements.

Try using `\(.*?\)` or `\([^)]*\)` to match the portion of the string surrounded by parenthesis inclusive.

If you want it to optionally eat up surrounding whitespace, put a `\s*` either side of the regex, or do a trim on the result.

Comment: Thanks alex, this works perfectly now (except I had to use the \\ escape sequence before the left and right parenthesis: \\(.*?\\).

Answer (score 0):

Your first example prints the original string because the `replace()` method doesn't perform a regex replacement.  It's trying to replace the literal string `((^))`, which of course is not present.

However, you would have gotten the same result if you had used `replaceAll()` or `replaceFirst()`.  The `^` in your regex is a zero-width assertion; it doesn't *consume* any characters, it just anchors the match to the beginning of the string.  The result I would expect to see from your second example is

```
> 56.0F (13.3C)
>
>
```

In other words, the whole string (`group(0)`) and two empty strings (`group(1)` and `group(2)`).  That's because both sets of parens are interpreted as capturing groups.  If you want to match the (literal) parentheses and their contents, you can use:

```
String exp = "\\(.*?\\)";
```

...or even better:

```
String exp = "\\([^()]*\\)";
```

There's no need to use capturing groups at all.